# Defining anchor tags in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, anchor

I am working with VS 2010 C#. I have an xml file where I define navigation links for my menus. I have defined some anchor tags in xml file but when I read the xml in code behind it doesn't show me the acnhor tags. I am even encoding it using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode. I don't know why the anchor tags are being omitted.Please help

Sample of XML file

```
<Navigation>
  <MenuItem>
   <a href="">....</a>
    </MenuItem>
  </Navigation>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the XML file and what you're doing to test that it doesn't contain the elements you expect?

Comment: Simply when I debug the code I don't see anchor tag in the node value and hence not rendered on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your anchor links in CDATA node. Something like below

```
<Navigation>
 <MenuItem>
  <![CDATA[<a href="">....</a>]]>
 </MenuItem>
</Navigation>
```

While reading from this XML, the inbuild XML parser will directly read the value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It reads the anchor tag now but doesn't render it like a hyperlink but simple text like <a href""></a>